# Prove that this logical statement is a tautology

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$$\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left( \left( \neg C \land D \right) \land \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \land \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \right) \implies \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]  $$

I started by rewriting the implication:
$$\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \neg\left( \left( \neg C \land D \right) \land \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \land \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]$$

Simplify:

$$\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left( \neg \left( \neg C \land D \right) \lor \neg \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \lor \neg \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]$$

$$\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left( C \lor \neg D \lor  \left( \neg A \land  E \right) \lor  \left( \neg F \land G \right) \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]$$

Expand:

$$\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor  \left(  C \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right) \lor \left( \neg D \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right) \lor  \left( \left( \neg A \land  E \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right) \lor \left( \left( \neg F \land G  \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right)$$

- $  C \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \Leftrightarrow (C \land D) \lor (C \land \neg E)$
- $\neg D \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \Leftrightarrow \neg D \land \neg E$
- $\left( \neg A \land  E \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \Leftrightarrow \neg A \land D \land E$
- $\left( \neg F \land G  \right) \land \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \Leftrightarrow (D \land \neg F \land G) \lor (\neg E \land \neg F \land G)$

$$ (A \land \neg B) \lor ((C \land D) \lor (C \land \neg E)) \lor (\neg D \land \neg E) \lor (\neg A \land D \land E) \lor ((D \land \neg F \land G) \lor (\neg E \land \neg F \land G))$$

I feel like this can be simplified even further. How do I continue from here?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you 'rewrote' the implication $P\implies Q$ in the first step as $\lnot P\land Q$ which is incorrect. An equivalent should be $(\lnot P) \lor Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, material implication should be $A \implies B \equiv \neg A \lor B$, so you made a mistake when rewriting the implication.

Secondly, the intuition should be that the implication must be true. So we review the premises $\neg C \land D$, $A \lor \neg E$, $F\lor \neg G$ to see how $D \lor \neg E$ can be derived. Indeed from $\neg C \land D$ we can derive $D$, so we write:

$$\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left( \left( \neg C \land D \right) \land \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \land \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \right) \implies \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]  $$

$$\equiv\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \neg  \left( \neg C \land D \right) \lor \neg \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \lor \neg \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \lor \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]  $$

$$\equiv\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left(C \lor \neg D \right) \lor \neg \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \lor \neg \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \lor \left( D \lor \neg E \right) \right]  $$

$$\equiv\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left(D \lor \neg D \right) \lor \neg \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \lor \neg \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \lor \left(C \lor \neg E \right) \right]  $$

$$\equiv\left( A \land \neg B \right) \lor \left[ \left(T \right) \lor \neg \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \lor \neg \left( F \lor \neg G \right) \lor \left(C \lor \neg E \right) \right]  $$

$$\equiv T$$

if the Law of Excluded Middle is allowed. To derive the tautology at the end, we observe that the tautology from LEM is conjuncted with other statements, so it must be a tautology as well.

Comment: So basically, disregarding the brackets which are unneded and rearranging the statements using associativity we get $C \lor \neg D \lor D \lor \neg E \lor \neg \left( A \lor \neg E \right) \lor \neg \left( F \lor \neg G \right)$ 

From here we can see that $\neg D \lor D$ is a tautology.

Comment: That is a good way to summarise it, yes.